# MySQL: JOIN and Conditional Statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, logic, conditional-statements

Can comeone help me to decipher the right logic of code needed for my query? I just can't find solutions about this or maybe my search queries are just vague. Lol.

I made a query and thought before it was fine but I just realized, just now, the inaccuracy of these. Here are what I've tried:

From a search page, for example we have this variable:

```
$variable = !empty($_POST["variable"]) ? $_POST['variable'] : "";
```

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
WHERE table2.column LIKE '%$variable%'
```

**RESULT 1**

- If `$variable` has no value, only rows with respective data from `table2` are displaying.
- If `$variable` has a value, rows with respective data from `table2` and matching value are displaying.

---

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
     AND table2.column LIKE '%$variable%'
```

**RESULT 2**

- If `$variable` has no value, all rows are displaying.
- If `$variable` has a value, all rows are still displaying.

---

**DESIRED RESULT**

- If `$variable` has no value, all rows will be displayed.
- If `$variable` has a value, rows with respective data from `table2`
  and matching value will be displayed.

I already tried using `IF`, `CASE` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` *(something I found somewhere)* but still no luck. Am I forgetting something with here? Or I'm doing it wrong *(which is the truth)*?

I have an alternative way and that is using conditional statement with PHP *(which will be my last option)* but if this thing is possible with MySQL only then it's a hooray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've just gave another shot with `IF` clause and figured out the simplest query that I can think of. **It's now giving the desired result**, here's my query:

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
WHERE IF('$variable' != '', table2.column = '$variable', 1 = 1)
```

Successfully, I placed that `IF()` clause in the right place. If you guys have thoughts about this code or have a very better one than this, kindly share it :)

---

> **[ADDITIONAL]**
>
> This is an [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140809/mysql-join-and-conditional-statement/140818?noredirect=1#comment266637_140818) from @ypercubeᵀᴹ and I love it!
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     ...
>     ...
> FROM table1
> LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
> WHERE table2.column = '$variable' OR '$variable' = ''
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```sql
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
     AND (table2.column LIKE '%$variable%' OR $variable = '' OR $variable IS NULL)
```

If `$variable` is `NULL` or empty, then *all* records will be returned by the query. Otherwise, only matching records are returned.

Comment: I tried that already but it displays all the rows whether `$variable` has a value or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check through condition for join, must use inner join

```
$sql = "SELECT
...
...FROM table1";

if(!empty($variable)){
$sql = $sql." INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id WHERE table2.column LIKE '%$variable%'";
}
```

Comment: I have an alternative like that, using the conditional statement with PHP (which I'll use as the last option) but if there's possibility to do that purely in MySQL then I'll go with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT CP.*,CT.* FROM `ChecklistTasks` AS CT LEFT JOIN ChecklistPoints AS CP 
    ON CT.`pkTID` = CP.`fkTID` AND CP.`CheckPointName` LIKE '%var%'
```

OR

```
    SELECT CP.*,CT.* FROM `ChecklistTasks` AS CT LEFT JOIN ChecklistPoints AS CP 
    ON CT.`pkTID` = CP.`fkTID` AND CP.`CheckPointName` LIKE '%%'
```

So far your query is right .. it is processing correct result..you want